# translation in vue component

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

```js
if (self.form.pickupTime == '') {
  self.formError.pickupTime = 'Ready for pickup time is required.';
  status = false;
  return status;
} else {
  self.formError.pickupTime = '';
}
```

I need to translate 'ready for pickup time is required'. This is a `Vue` & `Laravel` file. Tried `{{ $t('vue.readytime') }}` but errors popped up. Any ideas?

Comment: Well, since you have to run a command (`npm run *`) in order to get the final js file you will not be able to add anything from PHP to JS this way. BTW: what errors why not share those as well?

Comment: https://github.com/rmariuzzo/Laravel-JS-Localization

Comment: Unexpected token, expected ; (2045:61)

 self.formError.pickupDate = '{{ $t('vue.readyt                                                                                            ime2') }}';

Answer (score 0):

you can define lang vars in some .blade.php file

```
var lang = {
  pickupTime: "{{ t('vue.readytime') }}",
};
```

and use lang var in vue component

```
self.formError.pickupTime = lang.pickupTime;
```

Comment: Alright thanks for the suggestion! Will try and update you soon if it works :)

Comment: it doesn't work. vue runs as usual with no errors, but the component doesnt appear anymore after i made those changes. any recommendations?